# My Relative Layout Design shows messy view of my widgets in graphic Layout view (Layout Editor) but it works well in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop a `RelativeLayout` in the Layout Manager of `Eclipse(Galileo)` with Windows XP

My `RelativeLayout` consists of

- some `TextViews`
- some `LinearLayouts` , each `Layouts` in turn contains some `Buttons` and `TextViews`

I have arranged it with the reference id one below one using property:

"**layout Below & Layout above etc.,**.

But in Layout editor it is showing some messy type and it looks fine in `Emulator`

How can I arrange it well and good in the `Emulator` itself.I have spent some 2 days for this.  can't get anything

Is this a system error? Or, are there any techniques to handle the `RelativeLayout`?

Guide me.

Thanks in advance !!

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_W2CaYMJagaZTVjMzY1YmMtMDE2My00OGQzLTkxMTEtMmYwMTVkNzFhZTgz
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B_W2CaYMJagaZTFiMTRkYWUtNDYwNi00YjY3LWI3MjctY2NkZWFjYjI3MjNm&hl=en_US

This is the Url I have posted my screen shots.. for Your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same situation for me trying to design relative layout with eclipse. Try to post your question on [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/) . It's not important issue for me, but if you'll find the answer - it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The layout editor is not really all that reliable, especially for relative layout. It's nice for some simple layouts, but a lot of the time with more complex layouts it won't render correctly. If you're doing anything complex, you pretty much have to get a feel for the XML elements, use them to the best of your ability, then try in the emulator (or on a device).

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use tools for layout creating.. for example http://www.droiddraw.org/